# Assign same value to multiple array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Hi i am trying to assign a single value to multiple dynamic array and nested array in single object.

here is here object:

```js
object = {
  metaForm: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'abc',
      AdditionalVal: []
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'abc',
      AdditionalVal: [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'add',
        compositeConfig: []
      }, ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'abc',
      AdditionalVal: [{
        id: 1,
        text: '123',
        compositeConfig: [{

          id: 1,
          text: 'composit',
          compositeConfig: []

        }]
      }, ]
    }
  ],
  tabData: [{
      composite: false,
      compositeFieldList: [],
      id: 3576,
      tenantId: "1",
    },
    {
      composite: false,
      compositeFieldList: [{

          id: 1,
          text: 'composit2',
          compositeConfig: []

        },
        {

          id: 1,
          text: 'composit3',
          compositeConfig: []

        },
      ],
      id: 3576,
      tenantId: "1",
    },

  ]
}
```

Below is the o/p

```js
object = {
  metaForm: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'abc',
      AdditionalVal: [],
      isDisabled: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'abc',
      isDisabled: true,
      AdditionalVal: [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'add',
        isDisabled: true,
        compositeConfig: []
      }, ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'abc',
      isDisabled: true,
      AdditionalVal: [{
        id: 1,
        text: '123',
        isDisabled: true,
        compositeConfig: [{

          id: 1,
          text: 'composit',
          isDisabled: true,
          compositeConfig: []

        }]
      }, ]
    }
  ],
  tabData: [{
      composite: false,
      compositeFieldList: [],
      id: 3576,
      isDisabled: true,
      tenantId: "1",
    },
    {
      composite: false,
      isDisabled: true,
      compositeFieldList: [{

          id: 1,
          text: 'composit2',
          isDisabled: true,
          compositeConfig: []

        },
        {

          id: 1,
          text: 'composit3',
          isDisabled: true,
          compositeConfig: []

        },
      ],
      id: 3576,
      tenantId: "1",
    },

  ]
}
```

In the Above object a new value is assigned that is  "isDisabled: true" which is assigned to all the arrays as well as inner or nested array.

How to assign value to multiple dynamic arrays no matter how many arrays are there or nested arrays

Comment: Sorry @vinuta, I missed the "nested arrays" condition earlier. Updated my answer to handle that case now.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic way there.
You should just write simple recursion.
Something like this should work (pseudocode):

```
function traverseAndSetDisabled(obj) {
  if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for(child in obj) obj[child] = traverseAndSetDisabled(child)
  } else {
    obj.isDisabled = true;
  }

  return obj;
}
```

#### [UPDATE]

Working solution (result is 100% the same as user requested)

```
function traverseAndSetDisabled(obj) {
  if(typeof obj === 'object') {
    for(const child in obj) obj[child] = traverseAndSetDisabled(obj[child])
    if(!Array.isArray(obj)) {
      obj.isDisabled = true;
    }
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Comment: @vinuta this was just an example to point you in right direction. Why you expect ready solution instead of a little bit of thinking? I've updated answer with working code for your convenience...

Answer (score 0):

```
object.metaForm.forEach(i => {
 i.isDisabled = true;
 if(i.AdditionalVal.length){
  i.AdditionalVal.forEach(v => {
    if.isDisabled = true;
  })
 }
});
object.tabData.forEach(i => {
 i.isDisabled = true;
 if(i.compositeFieldList.length){
  i.compositeFieldList.forEach(c => {
   c.isDisabled = true;
  }
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Missed the "nested arrays" part in the question.

**Try this**:

```
function setProperty(object, key, value) {
  if(Array.isArray(object)){
    let newArray = [];
    object.forEach((obj, index) => {
      newArray.push(setProperty(obj, key, value));
    });
    return newArray;
  } else if(typeof object === 'object' && object != null) {
    object[key] = value;
    Object.entries(object).forEach(item => {
      if(Array.isArray(item[1])) {
        let listKey = item[0];
        let newList = setProperty(item[1], key, value);
        object[listKey] = newList;
      }
    });
    return object;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
setProperty(object, "isDisabled", true);
setProperty(object, "isDisabled", false);
setProperty(object, "someKey", "Some Value");
```

**Run the following code snippet for a demo**

```js
function setProperty(object, key, value) {
  if (Array.isArray(object)) {
    let newArray = [];
    object.forEach((obj, index) => {
      newArray.push(setProperty(obj, key, value));
    });
    return newArray;
  } else if (typeof object === 'object' && object != null) {
    object[key] = value;
    Object.entries(object).forEach(item => {
      if (Array.isArray(item[1])) {
        let listKey = item[0];
        let newList = setProperty(item[1], key, value);
        object[listKey] = newList;
      }
    });
    return object;
  }
}

function changeProp() {
  let object = {
    metaForm: [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'abc',
        AdditionalVal: []
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'abc',
        AdditionalVal: [{
          id: 1,
          text: 'add',
          compositeConfig: []
        }, ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'abc',
        AdditionalVal: [{
          id: 1,
          text: '123',
          compositeConfig: [{

            id: 1,
            text: 'composit',
            compositeConfig: []

          }]
        }, ]
      }
    ],
    tabData: [{
        composite: false,
        compositeFieldList: [],
        id: 3576,
        tenantId: "1",
      },
      {
        composite: false,
        compositeFieldList: [{

            id: 1,
            text: 'composit2',
            compositeConfig: []

          },
          {

            id: 1,
            text: 'composit3',
            compositeConfig: []

          },
        ],
        id: 3576,
        tenantId: "1",
      },

    ]
  };
  document.getElementById("old").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
  let name = document.getElementById("propertyName").value;
  if (name == null || name == "")
    name = "isDisabled"
  setProperty(object, name, true);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3> Enter the name of the property and click on the <strong>Set Property</strong> button.<br/> Default name is <i>isDisabled</i></h3>
  <input type="text" id="propertyName" name="propertyName" placeholder="Property name" />
  <button onclick="changeProp();">Set Property</button>
  <h2>Object</h2>
  <pre id="old">
</pre>
  <br/>
  <h2>Updated</h2>
  <pre id="result">
</pre>
</div>
```